# Possible to set icon size when opening Windows explorer from Powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, powershell

I have a Powershell script with UI which opens a specific folder in Windows Explorer like this:

```
ii $folderPath
```

The opened folders contain images and I'd like the script to automatically set the folder view to "Large Icons".  Is this possible?

Other info:Script is run as admin, Folder paths are on a network share, Don't want to set the view globally.

TNKS!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nirsoft tool [ShellBagsView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_bags_view.html) that allows you to **view** the information stored in the registry.

You might be able to create/modify a custom `Desktop.ini` file with a `[ViewState]` section and entries to get one of the modes `Icons, List, Details, Thumbnail, Tiles, Filmstrip` see this link [Desktop.ini Documentation](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html) but I didn't test that.

Comment: The author wants a PowerShell script.

Comment: We don't always get what we want.